# CSS: Why adjacent block elements shifting based on child elements

Tags: html, css, dom, document

```css
.super {
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.parent {
  border: 2px solid #0074d9;
  color: #0074d9;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.element {
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="super">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="element">Child1</div>
    <div class="element">Child2</div>
    <div class="element">Child3</div>
    <div class="element">Child4</div>
    <div class="element">Child5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="element">Child1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="element">Child1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="element">Child1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="element">Child1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above code, i'm trying to place some `inline-block` elements together with some existing child elements inside. However, there is some behaviour happening that i'm not able to understand.

The second and subsequent `parent` elements are shifting vertically below 1 row depending upon the child element size. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property that's used to set the vertical alignment of inline, inline-block, and table-cell elements.

To fix your issue you can simply add `vertical-align: top` on your `.parent` class.

```css
.super {
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.parent {
  border: 2px solid #0074d9;
  color: #0074d9;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.element {
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="super">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="element">Child1</div>
    <div class="element">Child2</div>
    <div class="element">Child3</div>
    <div class="element">Child4</div>
    <div class="element">Child5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="element">Child1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="element">Child1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="element">Child1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="element">Child1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```